# exog does not have full column rank. model estimation irrespective of the numerical accuracy of coefficient estimates, set check_rank=False

Tags: time, model, regression, linear-regression, panel-data

I have a list of companies A-Z, and I have a time data with month and year. I was able to conduct pooledOLS, FE and RE for yearly data, but now I have to do monthly analysis, meaning 01-2020, 02-2020... But everytime I run the model code I get the error :
exog does not have full column rank. If you wish to proceed with model estimation irrespective of the numerical accuracy of coefficient estimates, you can set check_rank=False.

```
    ROA Tobin Q Reddit Sentiment    News Content Sentiment  Total Assets    Age of Firm No of Employees
```

Firm    Time
Abbott Laboratories 201009  10.44391    1.982568    0.000000    0.000000    10.888611   122 90000
201010  8.81240 2.034400    0.000000    0.000000    10.957340   122 90000
201011  8.81240 2.034400    0.000000    0.000000    10.957340   122 90000
201012  8.78477 2.026348    0.000000    0.000000    10.959762   122 90000
201101  8.17690 1.849200    0.000000    0.000000    11.011619   123 90000
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
Zydus Lifesciences  202304  7.32110 2.251700    0.000000    0.054293    12.459024   20  8523
202305  7.32110 2.251700    0.334833    0.057278    12.459024   20  8523
202306  7.32110 2.251700    0.000000    0.110787    12.459024   20  8523
202307  7.32110 2.251700    0.000000    0.093434    12.459024   20  8523
202308  7.32110 2.251700    0.000000    0.063077    12.459024   20  8523
13429 rows × 7 columns

things I have tried:

1. there is no multicollinearity
2. changes to numeric
   Please help me, what do think I am doing wrong?